# Jquery Cant GET returning value when suming values of a checkbox

Tags: jquery, arrays

Im passing some values with ID's from selected check box's

Im collecting the values in an array to post however I also want to sum the values in the titles but I cant get it to do this...

where am I going wrong ? I know its in the calling of the variable that is returned but im not sure how to GET it

```
function doAlloMath(){


        var sum=0;

        alert($("input[name=alloInv]:checked").map(function () {return this.value;}).get().join(","));
        alert($("input[name=alloInv]:checked").map(function () {return this.title;}).get().join(","));
        alert($("input[name=alloInv]:checked").each(function (a,b) {sum += parseFloat ($(this.title)); return sum;}).get());



    }
```

Comment: what does `$(this.title)` contain?

Comment: Would you mind posting a small sample of your HTML, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A checkbox does'nt have a value unless it's explicitly set. To see if the checkbox is checked or not you need to use `prop('checked');`

You could try something more like this:

```
function doAlloMath() {
    var sum = 0,
        elm = $("input[name=alloInv]:checked"),

        values = elm.map(function() {
            return this.value;
        }).get().join(","),

        titles = elm.map(function() {
            return this.title;
        }).get().join(",");

    elm.each(function(idx, elem) {
        sum += parseFloat(this.title);
    });

    console.log(sum);
    console.log(values);
    console.log(titles);
}​
```

Comment: Hmm Sorry adeneo , Im collected the checked values alright, im having difficulty when trying to sum the title values, Im creating the object just dont know quite how access the sum'd value

Comment: Ok Ive got this to work really well, your missing the .get() from the }).join() at the end of each elm.map call but thats only thing...

However something WIERD is happening with SUM function the arrays show the figures correctly but the maths is WRONG ?

7.93

admin_...nts.asp (line 39)

2018386

admin_...nts.asp (line 40)

7.93

admin_...nts.asp (line 41)

15.86

admin_...nts.asp (line 39)

2018386,2018375

admin_...nts.asp (line 40)

7.93,8.74

admin_...nts.asp (line 41)

23.79

admin_...nts.asp (line 39)

2018386,2018375,2018372

admin_...nts.asp (line 40)

7.93,8.74,7.88

Comment: I actually remove the get()'s, as I did'nt think you'd need them, but my thinking was off, you do of course need them, otherwise you'd be trying to join objects, which does'nt work. Why the math is off I don't know, I'll add a seperate each function to the code above, see how that works, but it should iterate the exact same values as the map function would ?

Comment: The elm.each function is returning the following values...

13.94,13.94,13.94

Whilst the var titles = elm.map( is returning the proper values

13.94,71.81,7.3 which takes us all the way back to the original question the elm.each returns whichever the first title value is for howver many checkboxs are selected

Comment: That should'nt be possible. The each function should add them up, and at the end when they are console.log'ed the sum of all of them should show. Are you doing it like in the code above ?

Comment: function doAlloMath(){
   
 
   var mysum=0,
   sumup=0,
   mytitles="";
   
   elm=$("input[name=alloInv]:checked");
   
   var values = elm.map(function() {
    return this.value;
   }).get().join(",");
   
   var titles = elm.map(function() {
    return this.title;
   }).get().join(",");
   
   
   var sumup= elm.map(function(){
    
    sumup +=  parseFloat(this.title);
    return sumup;
   });
   
 
 
   console.log(values);
   console.log(titles);
   console.log(sumup[sumup.length-1])
  

   
  }

Comment: You're still using a map and a return value in the summing up of the titles, and the titles are of course numbers, and once they are summed up they are not an array that you can access with bracket notation, but just a number. Here's an example [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pcZsU/)

Answer (score 1):

I think your $(this.title) may be pointing to something unexpected in the context of $.each()

Comment: tHanks Hippocrates, yes its pointing to the first title value and not looping through where the MAP function loops through, but how do I get at the value summed from the map function ?

Comment: You should use b to reference it rather than this. the second argument to the each function is an anonymous function that is automatically passed 2 arguments. The first is the index, second is the value. In your case, this is b. Use b.val() within the anonymous function to get the value fo the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your HTML looks something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="alloInv" value="10.0" />
<input type="checkbox" name="alloInv" value="20.0" />
```

To sum what is checked, you may use the following:

```
var sum = 0;
$('input[name="alloInv"]').filter(':checked').each(function() {
    sum += parseFloat(this.value);
});
alert(sum);
```